# Laravel iframe Load denied by X-Frame-Options, does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, iframe

i'm using laravel framework in my web with Apache Server
i try to make my own widget using iframe
when i load my widget in other web i get this error on firebug:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://gotongroyong.fund/widgetShow/Forgotten-By-The-Fatherland-Vergeten-Door-Het-Vaderland does not permit cross-origin framing.

i already add `Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"` in .htaccess
 and `Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` in httpd.conf in Apache folder

i also already add`<?php header("X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT"); ?>` in page i wanna show in iframe

is anyone know how to fix it? or i add that code in wrong line / place ?
thx